# Spring & Couchbase - how to create indexes via code

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, couchbase, sql++

My Spring Boot app is using Couchbase 5.1 community.

My app needs both a primary & several secondary indexes.

Currently, in order to create the needed indexes, I access the UI and the `query` page and manually create the indexes that the app needs [as described here](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/createindex.html).

I was looking for a way to do it automatically via code, so when the app is starting, it will check if the indexes are missing and will create them if needed.

Is there a way to do it via Spring Data or via the Couchbase client?

Comment: That should be possible with N1QL query - http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.5.6/com/couchbase/client/java/query/Index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how I solve it:

```
import com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket;

public class MyCouchBaseRepository{

private Bucket bucket;

public MyCouchBaseRepository(<My Repository that extends CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository>  myRepository){
    bucket = myRepository.getCouchbaseOperations().getCouchbaseBucket();
     createIndices();
}


private void createIndices(){

   bucket.bucketManager().createN1qlPrimaryIndex(true, false)

   bucket.query(N1qlQuery.simple("CREATE INDEX xyz ON `myBucket`(userId) WHERE _class = 'com.example.User'"))
   ...       

}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create them by using the DSL from the index class. There's an example of using it in the documentation under "[Indexing the Data: N1QL & GSI](https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/2.7/sample-app-backend.html#indexing-the-data-n1ql-gsi)"

From that example:

> You can also create secondary indexes on specific fields of the JSON,
>   for better performance:
>
> `Index.createIndex("index_name").on(bucket.name(), "field_to_index")`
>
> In this case, give a name to your index, specify the target bucket AND
>   the field(s) in the JSON to index.

If the index already exists, there will be an `IndexAlreadyExistsException` ([see documentation](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.7.1/)), so you'll need to check for that.